# Linking error when using Rust code in C with CMake

Tags: c, gcc, rust, cmake, linker-errors

Linking problem when using Rust code in C with **CMake** .

I'm trying to incorporate some Rust code into my C project using **CMake**. I have successfully compiled the Rust code, generating `librust_lib.a` as the Rust static library. I passed this library to the linker in my CMake configuration. However, when I try to compile the C project, I encounter the following error:

> undefined reference to `rust_function`

Here's a summary of my project structure and configuration:

`toolchain-gcc.cmake:`

This is the configuration file used by CMake to set up the GCC toolchain. It sets various options and variables related to the cross-compilation environment.

```
# Configures CMake for using GCC

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME           Generic)
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILE}g++)
find_program(CMAKE_READELF      ${CROSS_COMPILE}readelf)

set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_ASM .elf)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_C .elf)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_CXX .elf)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE gcc_version OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

    set(abi_options -mcpu=cortex-a5 -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4
        -mfloat-abi=hard -mno-unaligned-access)
    set(partial_link_options)
    set(libc_file_name ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/components/newlib/armca5/libc.a)
    set(libm_file_name ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/components/newlib/armca5/libm.a)

    # specify the location of the Rust library file rust_lib.a
    set(rust_lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rust_lib.a)

if(CONFIG_ENABLE_GCC_LTO)
    set(lto_compile_option -flto -ffat-lto-objects)
    set(lto_link_option -flto)
endif()

add_compile_options(${abi_options} -g -Os ${lto_compile_option}
    -Wall
    -fno-strict-aliasing
    -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
)
add_link_options(${abi_options} -Os ${lto_link_option})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics")

# GNU ar will alreay create index
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH "")

if(WITH_WERROR)
    add_compile_options(-Werror)
endif()

if(WITH_LINK_CREF)
    set(link_cref_option -Wl,-cref)
endif()

set(multilib_opions ${abi_options})
if((${gcc_version} VERSION_GREATER 8) AND (CONFIG_CPU_ARM_CA5))
    set(multilib_opions -march=armv7-a+neon-vfpv4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard)
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${multilib_opions} --print-file-name libgcc.a
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE libgcc_file_name
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

`CMakeLists.txt:`

This is the main CMake configuration file for the project. It includes the toolchain-gcc.cmake file and sets up the project build process.

```
include(toolchain-gcc.cmake)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# Use a global property to collect all application libraries
define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY app_libraries
    BRIEF_DOCS "app libraries"
    FULL_DOCS "app libraries"
)

# Other configuration options...

# "all_libs" is a target to link all app libraries
set(target all_libs)
set(all_libs_out ${out_lib_dir}/all_libs.a)
get_property(app_libraries GLOBAL PROPERTY app_libraries)

# Append the rust library to the list of application libraries
# to ensure it is linked during the build process
list(APPEND app_libraries ${libc_file_name} ${libm_file_name} ${libgcc_file_name} ${QL_LIBS_PATH} ${rust_lib})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${all_libs_out}
    COMMAND python3 ${groupgen_py} --base ${BINARY_TOP_DIR} ${all_libs_out} ${app_libraries}
    DEPENDS ${groupgen_py} ${app_libraries}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_TOP_DIR}
)
add_custom_target(build_${target} DEPENDS ${all_libs_out})
add_library(${target} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${all_libs_out})
add_dependencies(${target} build_${target})
```

rust_lib/lib.rs:

This is the Rust source code file that contains the `rust_function()`.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_function() {
    // Rust function implementation...
}
```

rust_lib/Cargo.toml:

This is the Cargo manifest file for the Rust library.

```
[lib]
name = "rust_lib"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

# Other Rust configuration options...
```

main.h:

This is the header file for main.c that declares the `rust_function()`

```
void rust_function();
```

main.c:

This is the C source code file that calls the `rust_function()`.

```
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    // Other code...

    rust_function();

    // Other code...

    return 0;
}
```

Despite successfully compiling the Rust code and passing the `librust_lib.a` library to the linker in my CMake configuration, I encounter the following error during the compilation of the C project:

> undefined reference to `rust_function`

To investigate further, I used the `nm -gC` command to verify the symbols present in the Rust object file (`librust_lib.a`), and it does contain the rust_function symbol.

I'm unsure why the linker cannot find the reference to rust_function. Am I missing any additional configuration?

Comment: `include(toolchain-gcc.cmake)` - This is a **wrong way** of inclusion of a toolchain file in CMake. The correct way is to assign path to the toolchain file to CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling. The toolchain will be activated upon the first `project()` call.

Comment: What's the actual linker invocation if you compile with the `VERBOSE=1` environment variable set? Does the lib get linked?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your feedback. Upon trying the `VERBOSE=1` option, I have observed that the actual linker invocation does not include the `librust_lib.a` library.